# Dynamically add values to newly created dropdownlist instead of previously created

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have to add a new row by clicking add button in a cart. The row contains 3 textboxes and 1 dropdownlist. In dropdownlist the values are from database.

When I add another row the values from database are added to the previous dropdownlist and the new one becomes empty. I have to add in it new one instead of first row.

How can I proceed? I'd prefer to use the jQuery javascript library.

This is my code:

```
$("#addItems").click(function() { $.getJSON('Servlet1”',function(json){

    $('<tr id="shipdetail" style="margin-top:20px;"><td><input  type="text" id="cptd"/></td><td><select id="productopt"  tabindex="1"></select></td><td><span class="activeMinus"></span><input  name="quantity" id=1 class="input-quantity" value=1><span class="activePlus"></span></td><td id="tdataid"></td><td class="remove"></td></tr>').appendTo(".cptb2"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        $('<option>'+json[i].productName+'</option>').appendTo("#productopt");
    }
}): $('#productopt').change(function(){

    var code = $("#productopt").val();
    var name= code.split(']');
    var s=name[1];
    $.post('ProductsInfo',
    {
        productName:s
    },
    function(json){

        document.getElementById("cptd").value=json.code

        document.getElementById("tdataid").innerHTML=json.price;
        $("#productopt").empty();
        $('<option>'+json.name+'</option>').appendTo("#productopt");

    });
});
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: no one can help without getting an idea what you are actually doing, in code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you give the same id to each created `select`. This violates the HTML convention - the id of an element must be unique. If there are several elements with the same id, selecting by that id usually returns the first matched element (in your case the `select` in the first row).

To avoid this problem you could append a unique number to the id (`productopt_1`, `productopt_2` etc) or create a `select` with its contents first and then append it to the row:

```
$('#additems').click(function() {
   $.getJSON('Servlet1', function(json) {
      var row = $('<tr id="shipdetail" style="margin-top:20px;"></tr>');
      row.append($('<td><input  type="text" id="cptd"/></td>'));

      var select = $('<select class="productopt" tabindex="1"></select>');
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         select.append($('<option>'+json[i].productName+'</option>'));
      }

      row.append($('<td></td>').append(select));

      // Append the rest of markup
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are creating a template with a specific id for the select element of productopt. Each time you create this template you will create a dom element with a duplicated id. This means that the selector in your appendTo will probably just append to the first one it finds.

If you capture the results of your template statement into a variable e.g.

```
var template = $('<tr id="shipdetail" style="margin-top:20px;"><td><input  type="text" id="cptd"/></td><td><select tabindex="1"></select></td><td><span class="activeMinus"></span><input  name="quantity" id=1 class="input-quantity" value=1><span class="activePlus"></span></td><td id="tdataid"></td><td class="remove"></td></tr>').appendTo(".cptb2");
```

you can then scope your appendTo selector to the template and it will be more likely to work. Notice that you don't need an id on the select element this way.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $('<option>'+json[i].productName+'</option>').appendTo("select", template);
}
```